# I can i play a soud when loading process is at 25%?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, preloader

***Hi, is my second time here so if some one can help me to i can play a sound from library when loading process is at 25%, 50% and 75% of total loaded...***

**I will give you my code:**

```
var mysound:MySound = new MySound();
var soundPlaying:Boolean = false;

function checkingProgresssound(event:ProgressEvent):void{
var procentLoadeds:Number = event.bytesLoaded/event.bytesTotal*100;

if(procentLoadeds/4 == 25){ //check if loaded mor then 25% and sound isn't playing
mysound.play();
soundPlaying = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your var procentLoadeds is already a percent?
If it's the case why do you divide it by 4?

Comment: becouse if i just put "== 25" is not play the sound, but id i put "procentLoadeds/4 == 25" the FLAS CS6 loads the song, but still not playing...